# Get SubMenuItem I just clicked on in other window

Tags: winapi, menu, submenu, menubar

I want to get the text of any menu item. It works great for `top-level menu` (terminology from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647553(v=vs.85).aspx), but I do not understand how to get it work with `sub-menu items`.

For example I have the following menu structure:

1. File

   1. Open

      1. Project
      2. Solution
   2. Close
2. Exit

I want to be able to navigate to `File`->`Open`->`Solution` and when user clicks on it get the text `Solution'.

Here is the code for top level menu (when I click on `File`):

```
                MSLLHOOKSTRUCT ms = new MSLLHOOKSTRUCT();
                ms = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                IntPtr win = WindowFromPoint(ms.pt);

                IntPtr menu = GetMenu(win);
                int menuItem = MenuItemFromPoint(win, menu, ms.pt);
                IntPtr subMenu = GetSubMenu(menu, menuItem); // this is not used for top level and is useless for submenus

                StringBuilder menuName = new StringBuilder(0x20);
                GetMenuString(menu, (uint)menuItem, menuName, 0x20, (uint)ModifyMenu.MF_BYPOSITION);
```

But when I click on `Open` or `Solution` submenus this does not work, even `GetSubMenu` function does not work, becase `WindowFromPoint` returns wrong handler and both `GetMenu` and `GetSubMenu` return 0 (so basically when I click on submenu I do not have an achor to navigate from nor I can find any function to get the menu item by Point, like `WindowFromPoint`. `MenuItemFromPoint` return -1, probably because my Window handler is wrong).

Is there any other WinAPI function I am missing to achieve this?

Comment: Forget what you're doing, use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). That's what it's for.

Comment: Thanks!!! This is a great advice, your approach is way better.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, there is an error in MSDN article "MenuItemFromPoint function": for parameter "ptScreen" you must use screen coordinates (but not client coordinates as there).